# Why Text property of a DatePicker still contains value?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am building a WPF/C# application and I have several DatePicker-s which I reference using this construct:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
{
    DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)this.FindName(Constants.DP_PRODUCT_PREFIX + (i + 1));
    dp.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2017, 12, 31);
    dp.IsEnabled = true;
    dp.Opacity = 1;
    dp.Text = "";
 }
```

However even if I set

```
dp.Text = "",
```

the DatePickers still show their textfield with 31/12/2017.

Note: I want my DatePicker to be set to a default value of my choosing which in this case is 31.12.2017

What do I do wrong? Is it maybe the time when I run this code, it doesn't apply the change?

Comment: set the `SelectedDate` to `null` : `dp.SelectedDate = null;`

Comment: Yes, it is the easiest answer, I know.

Comment: You could make a 'not so nice' solution by setting the 'Tag' property to 'true' or 'false', whether you want to display the selected date or not. And then create a style for the 'DatePicker' and change the 'Visibility' of the text.

Comment: do you want user to select Date ? but you want the default selected date as you provided ? OR  you just dont want user to select date ? the date should be as you provided ?

Comment: @SyedMunisAli I want my DatePicker to be set to a chosen date but the text-field should be empty.

Comment: All of the controls in `WPF` work towards the MvvM. So the `Text` property relies on the `SelectedDate` and `SelectedDate` should be populated from ViewModel. If you would set up this way all of this would go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find DatePickerTextBox in DatePicker Template(which displays SelectedDate value) to assign new value.The default name for DatePickerTextBox in Template was "PART_TextBox" so you can find it from Template like this

```
dp.Loaded += (ee, ss) =>
        {
            var template = dp.Template;
            var t = template.FindName("PART_TextBox", dp) as DatePickerTextBox;
            if (t != null)
                t.Text = "";
        };
```

put the code in Loaded event to make sure DatePickerTextBox is not null.You can also see DatePicker Template by right click on the control then select edit style.